# Is there a relationship between $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\left({\frac {1}{2}}\right)^{n} = 1$ and $\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2} \,dx = 1$?

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, visualization, geometric-series

A classic example of an infinite series that converges is:

${\displaystyle {\frac {1}{2}}+{\frac {1}{4}}+{\frac {1}{8}}+{\frac {1}{16}}+\cdots =\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\left({\frac {1}{2}}\right)^{n}=1.}$

A classic example of an infinite integral that converges is:

$\displaystyle\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2} \,dx = 1.$

They feel very similar! But not quite the same. Is there a way to think about one in terms of the other?

I ask partly because I want to borrow the nice geometric illustrations that the former converges (like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1/2_%2B_1/4_%2B_1/8_%2B_1/16_%2B_%E2%8B%AF#/media/File:Geometric_Segment.svg), or similarly for [other geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#/media/File:GeometricSquares.svg)) to show the latter converging. ([Related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2642392/geometric-or-intuitive-proof-of-the-improper-integration-of-frac1x) about illustrating the geometry of $\frac{1}{x}$ vs. $\frac{1}{x^2}$.)

Comment: The [Abel-Plana](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel–Plana_formula) formula may work.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can break the integral $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2}dx$ into a sum of integrals over intervals $[2^n,2^{n+1}]$:

$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2}dx = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_{2^n}^{2^{n+1}}\frac{1}{x^2}dx = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  \left(\frac{1}{2^n} - \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} \right) =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{n}}.$$

Comment: This is shocking.  +1

Comment: Very cool relationship! I assume you could basically do this with any integral and sum with the same values, right? Of course, they wouldn't be as nice, but still.

Comment: Whoa amazing!! Thank you so much! Could you elaborate on why $\frac{1}{2^n} - \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$ simplifies to $\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$ in the second-to-last step?

Comment: @Toph $\frac{1}{2^n}-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}=\frac{1}{2^n}(1-\frac{1}{2})=\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$

Answer (score 4):

Note that by the substitution $u=1/x$, we have the integral

$$\int_1^\infty  \frac{1}{x^2} dx=\int_0^1 1 du.$$

Meanwhile, we have the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{n}}-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}.$$

Both express the area of a unit block, the former by integrating, the latter by telescoping.

Comment: This is a cool way of thinking about it, & I learned the term “telescoping” (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series) — thank you! Trying to remember how substitution works… so like, integrating from 1 to $\infty$ turns into integrating from $\frac{1}{0}$ to $\frac{1}{1}$? Sorry I'm slow but could you write the last step where you sub in $\frac{1}{x}$ and evaluate something minus something? And then in the latter the only term you're left with is $\frac{1}{2^0}$! Nice, nice

Comment: @Toph Right, for substitution it may help to check out [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#:~:text=In%20calculus%2C%20integration%20by%20substitution,the%20chain%20rule%20%22backwards%22.), including examples

Comment: @Toph Note $1/x^2= u^2, dx=-du/u^2$, $x=1\implies u=1$, $x=+\infty\implies u=0.$ The negative sign is dropped when the bounds are flipped.